# Creating a Fibonacci sequence in C

Tags: c, fibonacci

Consider a Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million. Find the sum of the even-valued terms. Your answer must be 4613732.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int a =0,b=1,c=0,sum=0;

   while (c<=10){
       int c=a+b;
       a=b;
       b=c;

       if(c%2==0){
           sum=sum+c;
       }
   }

   printf("%d",sum);

   return 0;
}
```

The output comes out to be blank. I tried 10 for smaller calculation time and the answer should be 2+8=10. I don't know what to do.

Comment: If using `gcc/clang` add `-Wshadowed` as a compiler option, on VS using `/W3` will do.  Your `int c=a+b;` shadows the `c` declared in `int a =0,b=1,c=0,sum=0;`. Adding the option to show shadowed variables to your normal compiler command line will save you a lot of grief...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this question

```
int c=a+b;
```

You are not using the value declared outside of the method Insted you are defining a new variable that only works on inside of your method. Try removing the `int` decleration inside the `while` loop  and It should work

Answer (score 0):

```
int c=a+b;
```

This doesn't modify the variable `c` that was declared outside the loop; it creates a new variable, whose scope is only the body of the loop.  You just want `c=a+b;` here.

You have another bug in that on the iteration of the loop which increases `c` beyond its limit value, that value may still be added to the sum, even though it should not.  For instance, if you replace the loop test with `while (c <= 7)`, you will still get 10 as the answer, instead of the correct 2.  Think about how to restructure the loop body to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is here:

```
int c = a + b;
```

You have redefined the variable `c` that shadows the original variable on each iteration. Remove the `int` declaration from there.

Also, note that you want to iterate up to **4 million** to obtain your desired results. So, change the iteration limit from `10` to `4000000`.*

---

<sup>* It is recommended declaring a macro constant on the top of the program to avoid *magical numbers*</sup>

Answer (score 0):

`int a = b+c` is the main problem in your code. That line of code re defines the entire variable declaration. So instead u want to put c = a+b

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int a =0,b=1,c=0,sum=0;

   while (c<=4000000){
       c=a+b; // just remove the `int` and this should fix it
       a=b;
       b=c;

       if(c%2==0){
           sum=sum+c;
       }
   }

   printf("%d",sum);

   return 0;
}
```

outputs: `4613732`